# In Yesod/Haskell, how do I use data from IO with the variable interpolation functionality?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, yesod

How do I take values from an IO monad and interpolate into a yesod widget?

For example, I want to interpolate the contents of a file into hamlet:

```
(readFile "test.txt") >>= \x -> toWidget $ [hamlet| <p> text: #{x} |]
```

or equivalently:

```
contents <- (readFile "test.txt")
toWidget $ [hamlet| <h2> foo #{contents} |]
```

There's something basic I'm not grasping about how interpolation interacts with IO since neither of these type checks:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘WidgetT App IO’ …
    Expected type: WidgetT App IO String
      Actual type: IO String
```

These errors occur in a getHomeR route function.

If I try to do something similar in GHCi with a predefined function, I get a different error. In the source file, I have a function:

```
makeContent body =
    [hamlet|
        <h2> foo
        <div> #{body}
    |]
```

in GHCi:

```
(readFile "test.txt") >>= \x -> makeContent x
```

And I get an error due to insufficient arguments (I think this is because of some template magic I don't understand yet):

```
<interactive>:139:33:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘IO b’
                with actual type ‘t0 -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()’
    Relevant bindings include it :: IO b (bound at <interactive>:139:1)
    Probable cause: ‘makeContent’ is applied to too few arguments
```

Comment: Looks like you need a `liftIO` here.  Try `liftIO (readFile "test.txt") >>= \x -> ...`.  I haven't used Yesod or hamlet, but it appears that you have a `WidgetT` transformer on top of the `IO` monad, so you'll have to lift any `IO` action to be a `WidgetT` action using `liftIO` (the preferred way here).

Comment: that does the trick. I haven't used `liftIO` before. if you submit as an answer I'll accept it. I'm still wrapping my head around monad transformers so any additional explanation or pointers to relevant info would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with monad transformers, to convert from some monad `m` to a transformer `t m`, you have to use the `lift` function:

```
lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a
```

This is actually the defining method of the `MonadTrans` typeclass, so the implementation is specific to the transformer `t`.

If you want to perform `IO` actions inside a transformer, you'll have to define an instance for `MonadIO`, which has the `liftIO` method:

```
liftIO :: (MonadIO m) => IO a -> m a
```

an instance of `MonadIO` doesn't have to be a transformer, though, `IO` is an instance where `liftIO = id`.  These two functions are designed to let you "pull" actions up a transformer stack, for each level in the stack you would call `lift` or `liftIO` once.

For your case, you have the stack `WidgetT App IO`, with the transformer `WidgetT App` and the base monad `IO`, so you only need one call to `liftIO` to pull an `IO` action up to be an action in the `WidgetT App IO` monad.  So you would just do

```
liftIO (readFile "test.txt") >>= \x -> makeContent x
```

A lot of developers (including myself) find `liftIO` a bit of a burden to type when you have a lot of `IO` actions, so it's not uncommon to see something like

```
io :: MonadIO io => IO a -> io a
io = liftIO

putStrLnIO :: MonadIO io => String -> io ()
putStrLnIO = io . putStrLn

printIO :: (MonadIO io, Show a) => a -> io ()
printIO = io . print

readFileIO :: MonadIO io => FilePath -> io String
readFileIO = io . readFile
```

And so on.  If you find yourself using a lot of `liftIO`s in your code, this can help trim down on how many characters you need to type.